# Move value from row[i] to row[i+1], conditional on a common index

Tags: r, indexing

I would like to copy certain values in one row and return them to a different row conditioned upon common factors. 
Here, in each trial there are two individuals (a subject and an opponent), and I have data recorded for the subject only. I want to "invert" the data for the subject and paste that into the appropriate row--namely, where the subject was the opponent.

An example dataset:

```
df = data.frame(
  section = section,
  trial = c(rep(c(rep("trial1",2), rep("trial2",2)),2)),
  subject = rep(subjects,2),
  rank = c(rep(c(1,4,2,3),2)),
  count.given = rnorm(8, m=5, sd = 3),
  opponent = rep(NA,(length(section))),
  opponent.rank = rep(NA,(length(section))),
  count.received = rep(NA,(length(section))))
```

Here's df:

```
  section  trial subject rank count.given opponent opponent.rank count.received
1       1 trial1       a    1  11.0552711       NA            NA             NA
2       1 trial1       b    4   4.8118577       NA            NA             NA
3       1 trial2       c    2   8.9146090       NA            NA             NA
4       1 trial2       d    3  11.8599362       NA            NA             NA
5       2 trial1       a    1   0.8334179       NA            NA             NA
6       2 trial1       b    4   4.1636337       NA            NA             NA
7       2 trial2       c    2   4.6000360       NA            NA             NA
8       2 trial2       d    3   6.9078512       NA            NA             NA
```

Now my goal is to fill in the opponent columns with the appropriate data from the same section and same trial. For example, the first row corresponds to section 1,  trial 1, and subject "a"; the opponent is therefore section 1, trial 1, and subject "b". The opposite is also true: "a" is the opponent in the second line.

The goal is to update df as follows:

```
  section  trial subject rank count.given opponent opponent.rank count.received
1       1 trial1       a    1  11.0552711        b             4      4.8118577
2       1 trial1       b    4   4.8118577        a             1     11.0552711
3       1 trial1       c    2   8.9146090        d             3     11.8599362
4       1 trial1       d    3  11.8599362        c             2      8.9146090
5       2 trial2       a    1   0.8334179        b             4      4.1636337
6       2 trial2       b    4   4.1636337        a             1      0.8334179
7       2 trial2       c    2   4.6000360        d             3      6.9078512
8       2 trial2       d    3   6.9078512        c             2      4.6000360
```

I think the best way to do this will be to sort df by section and trial, and then create an index corresponding to [i] and [i+1] for each trial. Then the subject data from [i] get pasted into the opponent data for [i+1], and vice versa. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the modulus operator `%%` on the row index.

```
c(1:8) %% 2
[1] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

This would be used in an `if` statement within a `for` loop:

```
for(i in 1:8){
    if(i %% 2 == 0){
        df[i,]$opponent = df[i-1,]$subject
        df[i,]$opponent.rank = df[i-1,]$rank
        df[i,]$count.received = df[i-1,]$count.given
    }else{
        df[i,]$opponent = df[i+1,]$subject
        df[i,]$opponent.rank = df[i+1,]$rank
        df[i,]$count.received = df[i+1,]$count.given
    }
}
```

A shorter version would be:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if(i %% 2 == 0){
        df[i, c(6:8)] = df[i-1, c(3:5)]
    }else{
        df[i, c(6:8)] = df[i+1, c(3:5)]
    }
}
```

**PS:** I would recommend setting `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your `data.frame`.